# TypeScript SomeArray[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SomeArray[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Am venturing into the world of Angular 2 and TypeScript and hit this error. Looks like you can set _isScalar somewhere ... just not sure where this should be.

I am getting the following error (see commented line in code):

Type 'Rating[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Rating[]'

For the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp, JsonpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Rating } from './rating.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { IODataList } from '@microsoft/sp-odata-types';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientConfigurations, SPHttpClientConfiguration, SPHttpClientResponse, ODataVersion, ISPHttpClientConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

@Injectable()
// See: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-data-binding

export class RatingsService {
//constrauctor( private jsonp: Jsonp) { }
    constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }

    //var url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false`;

    private choices: Array<Rating> = [];

    public fetchData(): Observable<Rating[]> {

        console.log("BGW: Document location = " + document.location.href);
    // var url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false`;
        //var response = this.jsonp.get(url); //.map((response => response.json()));
        console.log("BGW: Ratings choices url = " + url); 

        //var choices: Array<Rating> = new Array<Rating>();
        var choices: Array<Rating> = new Array<Rating>();
        // choices._isScalar = true;
        //let choices: Observable<Rating[]> = new Observable<Rating>();

        if (document.location.href.indexOf("localhost") > 0)
        {
            // Send dummy data to the form.
            console.log("BGW: Local workbench in use");
            choices.push(new Rating("High"));
            choices.push(new Rating("Medium"));
            choices.push(new Rating("Low"));
            return choices; // *** ISSUE HERE ***
        }
        else
        {
            var url = "https://somewhere.sharepoint.com/sites/Development/Subsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Requirements')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName%20eq%20%27Requirement_x0020_Rating%27";
            console.log("BGW: Ratings choices url = " + url);
            // Ref: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular2-observables-http-separating-services-components/
            var response = this.http.get(url).map((response => response.json()));
            console.log("BGW: response = " + JSON.stringify(response));

            return response.map((choices: Array<any>) => {
                if (choices) {
                    choices.forEach((choice) => {
                        choices.push(new Rating(choice));
                    });
                }
                return choices;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are not returning an observable like you have specified:

```
public fetchData(): Observable<Rating[]>
```

but later on you are defining...

```
var choices: Array<Rating> = new Array<Rating>();
```

That is why you are getting the error. There is a mismatch between an Observable Array and "regular" Array. If you don't explicitly ***need*** to specify what you are returning, I would just remove the `Observable<Rating[]>` altogether.

Comment: @webtechy, did either answer help you with your problem? If so, would you kindly accept an answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of answer? :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an observable like:

```
return Observable.of<Rating[]>(choices);
```

which uses the static method [of](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of), but there are many other ways.

The reason you see the compiler error is because you specify the return type in the method signature:

```
public fetchData(): Observable<Rating[]>
```